# Parsing Adwords expression in Python

Tags: parsing, python-3.x, google-ads-api

I have a dataset of AdWords matching expression; that is, expressions that can be triggered by actual search queries. Those expressions follow the AdWords syntax with optional words, required words and negative words. I am seeking some parsing logic for those expressions in Python that would convert those strings into object-oriented algebraic representations. In particular, the representation should allow to test for a match against a given user query. Is there any code out there available to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by converting into an object my AdWords Expression :
Then you could do whatever you want with better memory performances !

```
class AdWordsExp :
def __init__ (self,awexp) :
    self.tokens = self.parse(awexp)[0]
    self.flag = self.parse(awexp)[1]

def parse (self, awexp) :
    tokens = []
    flag = []
    begin = awexp[0]
    if begin == ' ':
        awexp = awexp[1:]
        begin = awexp[0]
    if begin == '+' :
        result = awexp.split()
        for words in result :
            begin2 = words[0]
            memo = self.memoisation(words[1:])
            if begin2 == '+' :
                tokens.append(memo)
                flag.append(0)
            else :
                tokens.append(memo)
                flag.append(1)
    if begin == '"' :
        result = awexp.split()
        s=0
        f=0
        for words in result :
            if s == 0 :
                memo = self.memoisation(words[1:])
                tokens.append(memo)
                flag.append(0)
                s=1
            else :
                if f == 0 :
                    l = len(words)
                    if words[l-1] == '"' :
                        memo = self.memoisation(words[:l-1])
                        tokens.append(memo)
                        flag.append(0)
                        f=1
                    else :
                        memo = self.memoisation(words)
                        tokens.append(memo)
                        flag.append(0)
                else :
                    begin2 = words[0]
                    memo = self.memoisation(words[1:])
                    if begin2 == '+' :
                        tokens.append(memo)
                        flag.append(0)
                    else :
                        tokens.append(memo)
                        flag.append(1)
    if begin == '[' :
        result = awexp.split()
        s=0
        f=0
        for words in result :
            if s == 0 :
                memo = self.memoisation(words[1:])
                tokens.append(memo)
                flag.append(0)
                s=1
            else :
                if f == 0 :
                    l = len(words)
                    if words[l-1] == ']' :
                        memo = self.memoisation(words[:l-1])
                        tokens.append(memo)
                        flag.append(0)
                        f=1
                    else :
                        memo = self.memoisation(words)
                        tokens.append(memo)
                        flag.append(0)
                else :
                    begin2 = words[0]
                    memo = self.memoisation(words[1:])
                    if begin2 == '+' :
                        tokens.append(memo)
                        flag.append(0)
                    else :
                        tokens.append(memo)
                        flag.append(1)
    return [tokens,flag]
    #print ([tokens, flag,dico])

def memoisation (self, word) :
    l = len (dico)
    if word in dico :
        return dico[word]
    else :
        dico[word] = l+1
        return l+1
```